# vuetify : prepend button next vtabs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to add a button before the `vtabs` but my solution doesn't work. I this case, the content under the `vtabs` has a left margin due to the flex containing the button.
Do you have a solution to display the button before the v-tabs and to have the content under without margin ?

My code :

```
 <v-layout row>
          <v-flex shrink>
            <v-tooltip bottom>
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-btn v-on="on" dark fab small color="secondary" @click="showModaleAddActivite()">
                  <v-icon>add</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </template>
              <span>Ajouter une activité</span>
            </v-tooltip>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex grow>
            <!-- onglets -->
            <v-tabs grow show-arrows v-model="activiteUrlSelected" color="blue-grey" dark>
              <v-tabs-slider color="deep-purple darken-3"></v-tabs-slider>
              <!-- contenus des onglets -->
              <v-tab
                :href="'#'+activite.urlEncoded"
                :to="'#'+activite.urlEncoded"
                v-for="(activite, index) in club.activites"
                :key="index"
              >{{ activite.code }}</v-tab>
              <v-tabs-items>
                <v-tab-item
```

[image: vtabs]

Comment: May I ask what does the plus button do? Design-wise, it might be better to put it inside the `v-tabs`

Comment: The "plus" button does a ajax call to add a new tab.

Comment: So, I think it makes sense if it is placed inside the `v-tab`, but not at the same level. You could place a `v-toolbar` inside the `v-tab` and put the button inside the `v-toolbar`. There is an example: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tabs#tab on their website.

Comment: You are welcome